# session variable becoming null after some time

Tags: session

I have developed a web application which will perform slideshow of some images.I have jquery ajax web method call for this application

The images are rolling perfectly...But after some time it is stopping...I found out from logs that my session variable(here Session["Username"])  is becomming null.My code is

```
   [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static string GetNextImage()
    {
        try
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"] != null)
            {
                string username = HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"].ToString();
                RollingScreenBAL bal = new RollingScreenBAL();
                DetailsForSlideShow[] details = bal.GetDetailsForSlideShow(username);
                int count = details.Length;
                int i;

                for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Count"] == null)
                    {

                        HttpContext.Current.Session["GraphUrl"] = details[0].GraphUrl;
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["Count"] = i + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["Count"]) == i)
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.Session["GraphUrl"] = details[i].GraphUrl;
                            if (i == (count - 1))
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Session["Count"] = null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Session["Count"] = i + 1;
                            }
                            break;

                        }
                    }


                }

            }
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["GraphUrl"].ToString();



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ConfigurationManager configMgr = new ConfigurationManager();
            string traceFilePath = configMgr.GetTraceFilePath();
            StreamWriter traceFile = new StreamWriter(traceFilePath, true);
            traceFile.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace + "Current User is  " + **HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])**;
            traceFile.Close();
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"]) session value is becoming null..Can anyone please help me why it is going null? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Your session variable becomes null when the session times out (and is not re-established / re-initialized), or when you explicitly set a particular item in the Session dictionary to null.

Comment: Actually the images are rolling with time frame of few seconds only...but session value by default will last for 20 minutes...So i think session timeout cant be the reason in my case....